# Worklight studio v6 installation failed within Eclipse Juno for Java EE

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've got issues with installing Worklight studio within Eclipse Juno for Java EE.
I've followed the basic install and local archive steps, but both failed.

Here are the errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201306140657         (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140657)
  Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20130418_1206 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 8.0.0.v20130418_1206) requires 'bundle             org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Web Page Generation Core Plugin 7.2.500.v20130412_0352 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core 7.2.500.v20130412_0352)
To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: IBM Mobile Application Tools 6.0.0.201306140656 (com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140656)
To: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [6.0.0.201306140656]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201306140657 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201306140657)
To: com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Core 6.0.0.201306140656 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.core 6.0.0.201306140656)
To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core [7.2.0,8.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation done following the steps:
- install Eclipse Juno
- launch Eclipse from an new empty workspace folder
- install worklight from ibm update site
- restart Eclipse from my v5.0.6 workspace folder

Install OK and projects upgraded OK.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note. 
 It is necessary to use Eclipse Juno Java EE **SR2** to install IBM Worklight Studio, otherwise, using a lower Eclipse version, installation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

while installing worklight studio v6 with eclipse sr2 ,I also got the same error during installation... 
then i ***increases net speed then started installation again*** , then the error will not occur.. ;-)